# Ubuntu で最新パッケージ全てをダウンロードしたい

Tags: ubuntu

HPEの物理サーバにUbuntu 22.04をインストールして、サーバはオフラインで運用しています。
オフライン環境のため、パッケージのインストールができず、事前に最新パッケージのdebファイルをtarで固めて置いておくことになっています。（以下のファイル全て）

https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/allpackages

上記のパッケージファイルを一個一個ダウンロードしていると気が遠くなる作業なので、効率よく全てのパッケージをダウンロードする方法はないでしょうか？

考えたこととしてリポジトリサイトからwgetコマンドで持ってこようと思ったのですが、パッケージをダウンロードではなく「index.html」をダウンロードして上手くいかず。

https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/

何か効率よい方法があればご教示いただけると助かります。

Comment: lunar は Ubuntu 23.04 ですが、そのオフラインの Ubuntu 22.04(Jammy Jellyfish) をアップグレードするということでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu/Debian ではパッケージリポジトリをミラーリングする [apt-mirror](https://apt-mirror.github.io/) というコマンドが用意されています。

ローカルにパッケージをコピーした上で、HTTP (webサーバ) 等でクライアントからアクセス可能な状態にします。すべてをダウンロードするにはそれなりのディスク容量が必要となります。

> Ubuntuは、ローカルキャッシュを公式のUbuntuリポジトリと同期するための apt-mirror パッケージを提供します。ミラーは、 HTTP または FTP サーバーを介して構成して共有できます。ローカルシステムクライアントを含むソフトウェアパッケージ。
>
> 完全なミラーキャッシュを実現するには、サーバーにローカルリポジトリ用に予約された少なくとも 120G の空き領域が必要です。

**参考:**
[UbuntuおよびDebianシステムで「apt-mirror」を使用してローカルリポジトリを設定する](https://ja.linux-console.net/?p=1392#gsc.tab=0)
[How To Create A Local Debian/Ubuntu Mirror With apt-mirror](https://www.howtoforge.com/local_debian_ubuntu_mirror)

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます。アップデートではなく、最新のパッケージを置いておくだけです。こちら難しそうですが試してみます！